# Android HighChart : Not loading data first time with 50k Points

Tags: android, highcharts

I am using HighChart for rendering graphs on android devices. But on the first time, it is not showing all data points when data points are more than 10k. When I tried to zoom in or zoom out several times, all data points became visible. I need a graph with 50k points at least. I am testing with sample code provided by HighChartjs.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList dataList;
int noOfData = 50000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dataList = data();

    HIChartView chartView = findViewById(R.id.hc);

    chartView.plugins = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("boost"));

    HIOptions options = new HIOptions();


    HIChart chart = new HIChart();
    chart.setType("line");
    chart.setZoomType("x");
    options.setChart(chart);


    HIBoost boost = new HIBoost();
   boost.setUseGPUTranslations(true);
    options.setBoost(boost);

    HITitle title = new HITitle();

    options.setTitle(title);

    HISubtitle subtitle = new HISubtitle();
    subtitle.setText("Using the Boost module");
    options.setSubtitle(subtitle);

    HITooltip tooltip = new HITooltip();
    tooltip.setValueDecimals(2);
    options.setTooltip(tooltip);

    HILine line = new HILine();
    line.setData(dataList);
    int noOfData = this.dataList.size();
    title.setText("Highcharts drawing " +noOfData +" points");
    line.setLineWidth(1);
    options.setSeries(new ArrayList<HISeries>(Collections.singletonList(line)));
    chartView.setOptions(options);

}

private ArrayList data(){
  ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfData; i++) {
        dataList.add(i, (Math.random() * 100));
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

}

Getting error logs: Highcharts error #26: [www.highcharts.com/errors/26](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/26)

E/Highcharts: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to show 50k points on the chart. You have for example 1920px width of the screen - how to show 50k points on 1920px? 1px can't be smaller.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel  HighChartjs is supporting charts with 50K points. The issue is that it is not loading data points the first time. After some pinch zoom, it is showing all 50k points.

Comment: Yes, Highcharts supports 50k points on the chart. However, it groups them because it is not possible to show them all. Check this example (result in the console): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zv42forg/. Note, that user loads 50k points but Highcharts group them and show about 300-400 points. After zoom, the data is more precise because it is grouping fewer points.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Totally agree with you. I want to display the same kind of graph. The issue is that it is not loading the first time. Graph area is showing blank and in Logcat it is giving this error - www.highcharts.com/errors/26. When I try to zoom or pinch on that empty place, the graph appears and show all data points in the group. Like the example you send.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Have you checked `boost-canvas.js` is included and that it's included before `boost.js`?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I am working on Android framework provided by HighChart. Can't include js files directly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not Android expert. Check this tutorial: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/highcharts-android-wrapper-tutorial/. There you will find a description of how to use the export module by putting a specific provider in your app. Perhaps `boost-canvas` module can be loaded in the same way. Could you check it?

Comment: Raise same issue on Hichart Android Github. This is an issue and maybe solve in future releases. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/86